# get all computer accounts and remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove all the principal group memberships starting with the name  of all computer accounts in one specific ou.

I've tried browsing to the OU with the AD provider, typing `gci` and getting a list of all the computers in the ou to find their `ADPrincipalGroupMembership` which works. Also, using `get-adcomputer -searchbase <ou> -filter *` works too. But I can't then remove every group that each machine is a member of.

When I then try to expand on that with `remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`, my input for the groups to remove are `system.string` and `remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` won't accept that. I have something like this so far/

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=blahblah' -Filter * | 
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf (Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "17"')
```

I've read help and examples but I can't find how to do this. I don't want to give up and just use the gui :)

thank you

Comment: Show us what you have started. The community will be able to help you better once you give us something to work with.

Comment: Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=blahblah' -Filter * | Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf (Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "*17*"') seems to work for the first computer in the ou

Comment: `-MemberOf` would accept an array of names but I dont think an array of objects. `-MemberOf (Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "17*"' | Select -ExpandProperty Name)` does that work? Also using `-like` means you have a astericks or something to match too

Comment: Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=blah' -Filter * | Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf (Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "*17*"' | select -ExpandProperty Name) seems to do the same thing, a computer near the bottom of the list still has groups that start with 17 in them when running Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership

Comment: `Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "17"' | select -ExpandProperty Name` does that command return the groups you expect? Again, normally `-like` is used with wildcards `-like "17*"`

Comment: yes, but for some reason this site is stripping out the asterisks in 'name -like "*17*"'. but the command does return the groups I want gone

Comment: You want to remove the computers from all groups starting with 17?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but only the computers located in a specific ou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...I am not able to test it to confirm it works, but I think it should.

```
$Comps = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=blahblah' -Filter * -Prop MemberOf 
Foreach ($Comp in $Comps)
{
    $Groups = $Comp.MemberOf | ? {$_ -like "CN=17*"}
    if ($Groups)
    {
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $Comp -MemberOf $Groups -Whatif #-Confirm $False
    }
}
```

Assuming it works with the -whatif statement, by default I believe that command will prompt you if you're sure about each removal which could be a pain so you could uncomment `-confirm $false` to try and avoid that.

Also it is assuming the distinguished name of each group is going to be something along the lines of

`CN=17groupA,OU=Computer Groups,OU=Computer,DC=TEST,DC=NET`

Comment: Thank you! really useful and helped me understand the workflow of making this happen